# How to get Neighbour td value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using DataTabele. I will get the neighbour td value when click the button in next td

### Table

```
<td class="">
    <span class="imei">imei1</span>
</td>
<td class="">
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Approve" class="btn-info approve">
        <input type="button" value="Reject" class="btn-warning reject" >
    </div>
</td>
```

### JS

```
DataTable.on('click', .approve', function(event) {
    // here I want get imei value   
});
```

In this click event. i want to get

Comment: Be a lot easier if you put the id of what the button was approving in the markup for the button...

Comment: It feels like we have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. If you have access to the way the table is structured, you should have it add unique id's to the buttons and `imei` spans.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the span's content with:

```
var spanContent = document.getElementById('imei').innerHTML;
```

However, this code doesn't consider any relation between the elements, I'm just using the `id` you've already set on the span. Since `id` properties are supposed to be unique, that should work just fine.

Comment: I have several rows like that.

Comment: I have modified question

Comment: Are you also using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have different ids and you want a generic solution for all rows. Try this.

```
var target = event.target,
    value;

while((target = target.parentNode) && (target.nodeName !== "TD")){}

value = target.previousSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
```

or a little more robust version

```
while((target = target.parentNode) && (target.nodeName !== "TR")){}

value = target.querySelector('.imei').innerHTML;
```

Comment: While this would work, traversing the DOM like that can easily lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Right, I'd better put those values in hidden field or in data attributes.